# Could you suggest a textbook for learning basic properties of spectrum of closed operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, book-recommendation, closed-map

I wish to learn the very basic properties of **the spectrum of Closed operators**. I may use these properties in the research in the Fluid dynamics/Differential equations.

**My attempts:-**
I searched in google. Search was disappointing.
I asked in Chat. I couldn't find the book.
[image]

I searched in the following textbooks

1. Textbook of Functional Analysis by V.K Krishnan[2E,PHI]
2. Functional Analysis-Balmohan Vishnu Limaye(2008, New Age International)
3. Foundations of Functional Analysis-Ponnusamy Saminathan  (2002, Alpha Science International, Ltd_India Alpha)
   I couldn't find a basic theory related to the spectrum of closed operators.
   I request you to suggest a very basic textbook for learning this topic.

Comment: What is your background? You could try Brezis' textbook.

Comment: @Yai0Phah I know basic properties of Banach space and Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications, by Erwin Kreyszig , is a very good book for self learning in functional analysis and operator theory.